# Input string was not in a correct format in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am updating the values in grid view. if i am updating the noofdays it will showing  `Input string was not in a correct` and how to give me some suggestion.
and i have other question when the employee apply leave before week it will take the data else it will show the message.
 how to write it logic.

code behind

```
leaveUpdateRow.NoOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);
```

ASPX

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="NoOfDays" HeaderText="Leave Period"></asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: leaveUpdateRow.NoOfDays is integer or string??

Comment: Before converting check it null or empty like if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
leaveUpdateRow.NoOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text) == NULL ? 0 :Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);
```

Comment: Your code is c# or vb ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran My code is C#

Comment: yep, Now you have changed that. now looks pretty.

Comment: so with mine u have come up with another answer?? lol :P

Comment: Your answer is wrong `Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text)` If the value is empty? then how can convert it? please change that

Comment: And i have changed my answer, please take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it

please check the value is integer before convert the values.

Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
leaveUpdateRow.NoOfDays=string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text)?0:Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);
```